# ansible find: get path of a directory from register

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong hence why I am seeking some help. I wish to search for a folder using ansible, locate the folder and copy its contents to another directory. This is what I have so far. I think I am stuck in the with_items section.

```
- name: Folder find and file copy
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    search_path: ~/oldfolder/backups
    id: patient_1234
    dest: "~/newfolder/{{ id }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Find directory using patterns
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ search_path }}/"
        file_type: directory
        patterns: "{{ id[:-4] }}*"
        recurse: yes
      register: find_matches

    - name: Print return information from the previous task
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: find_matches.files[0].path
      when: find_matches is defined

    - name: Copy from backup to destination
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "{{ dest }}"
        remote_src: yes
      with_items: "{{ find_matches.files }}"
```

Comment: ``ok: [192.168.1.8] => {
    "find_matches.files[0].path": "/home/test_user/oldfolder/backups/patient_1234"
}`` and the ansible user is the owner of both folders and yes the destination folder does exist. In terms of syntax, do you see anything wrong with the playbook?

Comment: the copy task return this ```ok: [192.168.1.8] => (item={'path': '/home/test_user/oldfolder/backups/patient_1234', 'mode': '0775', 'isdir': True, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, ...})```

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong. Usually when ansible says `ok`, the system is already in the desired state, and that's ansible's way of saying "there's nothing to do here". Have you checked to see if `/home/test_user/newfolder/` contains the results you want? The command output is mentioning `/home/test_user/old_folder` because that is the source, it doesn't mean that's where the result is stored

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out. This line needs to be``src: "{{ item.path }}/."``

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Folder find and file copy
  hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    search_path: ~/oldfolder/backups
    id: patient_1234
    dest: "~/newfolder/{{ id }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Find directory using patterns
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ search_path }}/"
        file_type: directory
        patterns: "{{ id[:-4] }}*"
        recurse: yes
      register: find_matches

    - name: Print return information from the previous task
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: find_matches.files[0].path
      when: find_matches is defined

    - name: Copy from backup to destination
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}/."
        dest: "{{ dest }}"
        remote_src: yes
      with_items: "{{ find_matches.files }}"
```

**Another option**

```
   - name: Copy from backup to destination
     ansible.builtin.shell: 'cp -r {{ item.path }}/. {{ dest }}'
     with_items: "{{ find_matches.files }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

change last copy block

- name: Copy from backup to destination
  ansible.builtin.copy:
  src: "{{ item.path }}/."
  dest: "{{ dest }}"
  remote_src: yes
  with_items: "{{ find_matches.files }}"

make sure you dont have /. in src

- name: Copy from backup to destination
  ansible.builtin.copy:
  src: "{{ item.path }}"
  dest: "{{ dest }}"
  remote_src: yes
  with_items: "{{ find_matches.files }}"